# Add a product to the cart via query string without form_key parameter in magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, magento2.3

I need to help for add form key to cart url. can you anyone help.

```
$urlValue="";
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $urlValue = $product->getStatus();

        $cartUrl = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
        $urlValue =  $cartUrl->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        $urlValue=str_replace(",,",",",$urlValue);
        if ($product->getConfigOptions() && 0) { 
        $urlValue .= strpos($urlValue, '?') !== false ? '&' : '?';
        $urlValue .= $product->getConfigOptions();
        }

        $getParams = [];

        $feed = $this->getFeed();

        if ($feed && $feed->getReportEnabled()) {
            $getParams['ff'] = $feed->getId();
            $getParams['fp'] = $product->getId();
        }

        $utmMap = [
            'utm_source'   => 'ga_source',
            'utm_medium'   => 'ga_medium',
            'utm_campaign' => 'ga_name',
            'utm_term'     => 'ga_term',
            'utm_content'  => 'ga_content',
        ];

        foreach ($utmMap as $key => $value) {
            if ($feed && $feed->getData($value)) {
                $getParams[$key] = $this->getFeed()->getData($value);
                if (preg_match('/{{product.*?}}/is', $getParams[$key])) {
                    $getParams[$key] = $this->dynamicAttribute->getLiquidValue(
                        $this,
                        $getParams[$key],
                        ['product' => $product]
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($getParams)>= 0) {
            $urlValue .= strpos($urlValue, '?') !== false ? '&' : '?';
            $urlValue .= http_build_query($getParams);

        }


        return $urlValue;
```

Comment: Can you show your code here @venkataprasad

Comment: $params = array(
        'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
        'product_id' => $productId
    );

Comment: Add this ['form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey()] before ['product' => $product],

Comment: Add this ['form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey()] before product params @venkatarasad

Comment: thanks. but product not added to cart through url.